# Hide HTML/JQuery table if empty (footable)

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Below is the source code from my website which shows an empty table produced from a PHP file that had no data to fill it, how can I hide these tables and strip the code from the page if the table is empty.

```
<form class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<table class="footable" cellspacing="0" class="group_table">
    <thead>
<tr id="price-table-custom-header">
        <th><center>head1</center></th>
        <th><center>Information</center></th>
        <th data-sort-initial="true"><center>head3</center></th>
        <th><center>Purchase</center></th>
</tr>
    </thead>  
<tbody> </tbody>
<tfoot class="hide-if-no-paging">
<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<div class="pagination pagination-centered">
<ul></ul>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: if you always start with empty table, why don't you use display:none?

Comment: the table is not empty on other pages.

Comment: @Scott the proper solution would be to find the place where table row data is generated and put the `<table>` output under condition `if (count($data)) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify if the tbody tag is empty and hide the whole table if it is.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($.trim($(".group_table tbody").text()).length == 0) {
     $('.group_table').hide();
   }                                           
});
```

Edit:

Your table has two class attributes, to add two classes, you should do this way:

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="group_table footable">
```

Js Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jsb3z0y4/

Comment: I edited my post, there was an error in your html, take a look.

Comment: i fixed it thanks for your help the problem was white space being treated as text

Comment: it still shows the header of the table?? take a look at my answer above this seems to work only problem is it breaks my pagination any ideas?

Comment: You are right but I have an identical table in a seperate tab it conflicts with same classes

Comment: You can add an id to the table and use it on the selector

Answer (score 0):

Why not check if it has any content and hide it if there isn't any.

```
var hasContent = $('.group_table tbody').text().trim();

if(!hasContent){
    $('.group_table tbody').hide();
}
```